# Literature on atmospheric modelling

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, reference-request

I need to understand some basics about atmospheric modelling, since I am working with data from the COSMO model for my thesis. My questions mainly concern model validation, like learning about the most common metrics to evaluate model accuracy. Therefore, does anybody have suggestions concerning good introductory textbooks for atmospheric modelling?

To clarify where I am coming from:

I am looking at regional climate data for the Antarctic as simulated by COSMO in Climate Mode driven by ERA-Interim. Observations in the region and for the period of interest are naturally sparse, so I wondered how I can validate the model data against the few observations there are. This led me to the question whether there are some general practices and statistical methods to validate output of an atmospheric model and hence the idea to ask for pointers to introductory textbooks.

Comment: Hi chriss, welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange.  We need a few more specifics to be able to address your question.  What kind of model is it?  General circulation weather model, climate model, chemistry model, full coupled earth system model, regional or global model?  Against what do you want to validate it?

Comment: @gerrit Thank you for the welcome. I have editted to be more specific, do you have other advice for me?

Comment: @chriss there are two separate questions here. validating model data when only few observations are present and validating output of an atmospheric model.

Answer (score 2):

"[Atmospheric modeling, data_assimilation and predictability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521796296)" by Euginia Kalnay, is an introductory book, which is good to get an overall overview of the subject.

If you are more interested in the numerics I would recommend "[Numerical Methods for Fluid Dynamics](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441964113)" by Dale R. Durran.

Comment: Thanks for the "Numerical Methods" recommendation. Can need it in a li'l programming project i am doing :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to reference Statistical Methods in the Atmospheric Sciences, by Wilks in your thesis.
Also this [webpage](https://www.cawcr.gov.au/projects/verification/) concerning different aspects of many metrics used in verifying forecasts.